# обработка строки из str в int

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

в модуле pyautogui есть функция position(), которая возвращает координаты курсора мыши в данный момент
но возвращает она их в виде такой **строки**: Point(x=567, y=350)
Как обработать эту строку так, чтобы на выходе было два **числовых** значения(соответственно x и y), с которыми уже можно работать как с числами? Отсечь все лишнее.

Comment: Как вы определили, что это строка? typeof(position()) показывает именно str?

Answer (score 7):

`position()` из PyAutoGui возвращает никакую не строку, а кортеж из двух чисел. Т.е. именно два **числовых** значения, как вам и требуется.